# Does a dead Basilisk's eyes still kill?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, basilisk

If a Basilisk was killed without being blinded, would opening it's eyes (presuming they were closed on death) still cause instant death in the viewer?

**Edit:** I'd do this myself, but I'm not sure how. This question should be on hold until [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123567/how-do-basilisk-eyes-actually-work?lq=1) question is answered to give a greater understanding to the actual question.

Comment: This is a good question!

Comment: Possibly, but first you'd need to determine what makes the eyes deadly in the first place.Could Slytherian have placed a spell on the basilisk?  Is the spell broken when the basilisk dies? Or could it be something chemical within the basilisk? Interesting question though +1

Comment: @Scanner I smell another question! I'll post it in a second.

Comment: @Anoplexian, lol I'm going to make a guess that it's another basilisk question?!?! Look forward to seeing it!!

Comment: These questions appear to be semi-dupes. I'm not sure that as a supplementary question this is worthy of a separate question.

Comment: First thing that it made me think of was Greek Mythology, and Perseus using the severed head of Medusa.

Comment: @Richard I say they're related because they ask completely separate questions. I'd say it depends on the answer, and if an answer for the other one answers this question as well, I'd delete this one as a duplicate. Otherwise they'd be completely separate although entirely complementary questions. Whether or not someone looks at both and answers both on one of them is the real question, but the questions themselves are inherently different.

Comment: @Anoplexian - They're not asking separate questions. One is asking how its eyes work, the other is asking how its eyes work.

Comment: One is asking how it kills, the other is asking if it still works when **it's** killed.

Comment: @Anoplexian - It's possible one would answer the other. Attaching the rider "and does it still work if the Basilisk is dead?" would cover both bases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**It’s hard to know for sure, but I would guess not.**

We only really see one basilisk in canon – the basilisk in the Chamber of Secrets. Although there are descriptions and allusions to others, we don’t see them in enough detail to make a call on this one. And Fawkes unhelpfully blinds that basilisk and fills the eyes with blood.

JK Rowling’s mythology is not written in isolation; it draws inspiration from a lot of classical mythology. There’s one story about a basilisk – [the basilisk of Warsaw](http://blogs.forteana.org/node/107) – which suggests to me that post-mortem, a basilisk stare isn’t fatal:

> He declared that it really was a basilisk; it had the head of a cock, **the eyes of a toad**, a crest like a crown, a warty and scaly skin "covered all over with the hue of venomous animals," and a curved tail, bent over behind its body.

At this point, the basilisk has been killed and dragged out a cellar. It’s being examined by a physician. He must have looked at the eyes to know they looked like a toad, and he must have survived to tell the tale. Ergo, basilisk stare isn’t fatal if the creature is dead.

Comment: Nicely rounded answer with a solid speculation. Disappointed there's no canon, but regardless +1.